# Selective accessibility of methods in derived classes

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Recently I was attending an interview, where interviewer asked a tricky question related to inheritance. Question was based on c#.

We have base class `ClassA`, and it has two methods - `Method1()`, `Method2()`.

```
public class ClassA {
    void Method1();
    void Method2();
}
```

Now we inherit this class then create `ClassB`. Objects of `ClassB` should have `Method1` accessible outside, `Method2` should be hidden

```
public class ClassB : ClassA{
}

ClassB objB= new ClassB();

objB.Method1(); //should be accessible 
objB.Method2(); //should not be accessible.
```

Again we create another class `ClassC` from `ClassA`. 
Objects of `ClassC` should have `Method2` accessible outside, `Method1` should be hidden

```
public class ClassC : ClassA{
}

ClassC objC= new ClassC();

objC.Method1(); //should not be accessible 
objC.Method2(); //should be accessible.
```

I have answered with private access modifier to the methods accordingly.  Interviewer didn't accept. Is there any wiser way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes. [protected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected). Although "should be hidden" is ambiguous and could mean `private`, `protected` or even `internal` depending on who it should be hidden from.

Comment: @BiesiGrr No, this is unfortunately wrong. The example is confusing because the `Main` method is inside the derived class. This is why it is possible to access the field `x`. Protected is not accessible outside of the class, only within the derived class

Comment: @BiesiGrr I was talking about the link that you posted. Have a look.

Comment: @MongZhu Oh I see. That's the Microsoft documentation however...

Comment: @BiesiGrr "That's the Microsoft documentation however" yeah, I wrote them a feedback, of how confusing this example is

Comment: I only now notice that `Method1` and `Method2` have different (?) requirements for accessibility. The comments on the code are confusing and don't match the description.

Comment: @BiesiGrr ". The comments on the code are confusing and don't match the description" I fixed that. Today is the "lets confuse the SO people" day ;)

Comment: @MongZhu Are you sure that's correct though? Could be that the comments were correct and the text was wrong...

Comment: Is it just me or would that be a code smell to anybody else, too?

Comment: @BiesiGrr everything is possible, but seeing it in a context of a test in an interview, the latter situation becomes quite improbable, why would you then need the second example of ClassC ?=!

Comment: @Fildor "would that be a code smell to anybody else, too?" That is probably exactly the correct answer to such an interview question ;) Post it for the people to prepare for their interviews ;)

Comment: @MongZhu Well, it doesn't really answer the question, nor does it solve anything. I'd probably state that I, personally - being tasked with that requirement - would question the design, _but_ if I _had to do it_ I'd do it in this and that way... Oh, I hate those "trap questions". As if the interviewee wasn't already under stress. That's just sadism in my book.

Comment: I generally dislike the idea of asking programming language syntax questions in interviews. Software Engineering is not about knowing the correct syntax for all use-cases by heart. You can always look that up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both methods should be `protected` in Class `A` which means that they are only visible internally to the object and to inherited classes.

Then in class `B`, reintroduce method `Method1` and make it `public`, calling the interited method.

And in class `C`, reintroduce method `Method2` and make it `public`, calling the interited method.

Use the [`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier) keyword when reintroducing methods with existing names to clarify the intention and prevent a compiler warning.

```
class A
{
    protected void Method1()
    {
    }

    protected void Method2()
    {
    }
}

class B: A
{
    public new void Method1()
    {
        base.Method1();
    }
}

class C : A
{
    public new void Method2()
    {
        base.Method2();
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.Method1(); // Not allowed
        a.Method2(); // Not allowed

        B b = new B();
        b.Method1();
        b.Method2(); // Not allowed

        C c = new C();
        c.Method1(); // Not allowed
        c.Method2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness and being encouraged to write it up as an answer:

*You shouldn't.* This design is a code smell. It hints to issues with interface separation (and probably more). So that would be the first thing, I would answer.

**But** followed by @NineBerry's approach, disclaiming *"If I wasn't allowed to review the design and just implement the requirement ..."*

Reasoning: The interviewer now knows I am aware of design issues and clean code but also I am proficient enough to do it despite my objections, because after all, there may be situations where a redesign would be out of question for whatever reason.